# Why socket.io returns multiple times for an event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I just started picking up socket.io. I'm trying to use it in angular.js and everything works fine. However, it keeps returning multiple times

**in my controller.js**

```
socketio.emit('GameOver',$scope.currentPlayer.Name);
      socketio.on('GameOverEmit',function(data){
        if(data === $rootScope.user.user_name){
          var result = {
            opponent : rdyplayers.user_name,
            result : "won"
          };
            // keep getting multiple result 
          console.log(result);
        }else{
          var result = {
            opponent : rdyplayers.user_name,
            result : "lose"
          };
            // keep getting multiple result 
          console.log(result);
        }
      });
```

In my server.js

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (client) {
​
           client.user_name = user.user_name;
​
          //Useful to know when someone connects
           console.log('\t socket.io:: player ' + client.user_name + ' connected');
           // playerturn
            client.on('PlayerTurn',function(data){
                 io.emit('PlayerTurnEmit',data);
​
            });
            // game over
            client.on('GameOver',function(data){
                 io.emit('GameOverEmit',data);
​
            });
            // button disabled
            client.on('PlayerButtonDisabled',function(data){
                io.emit('PlayerButtonDisabledEmit',data);
            });
               //When this client disconnects
           client.on('disconnect', function () {
                   //Useful to know when someone disconnects
               console.log('\t socket.io:: client disconnected ' + client.user_name );
               io.emit("disconnected",client.user_name);
           }); //client.on disconnect
​
       }); //io.sockets.on connection
```

Am I using socket.io in the correct way? In order to broadcast the data to everyone I just pass the data into an `emit` and take the data broadcast it by using `on` like pass the data to server and pass it back to the front-end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it caused by controller.js, whenever i revisit the page it will establish a new socket so what i did is whenever a user leave or close the tab it removes all the listener. 
i ended up solving it by adding getsocket in my service.js

```
ttt.factory('socketio', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
  'use strict';

  var socket = io.connect();
  return {
      on: function (eventName, callback) {
          socket.on(eventName, function () {
              var args = arguments;
              $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                  callback.apply(socket, args);
              });
          });
      },
      emit: function (eventName, data, callback) {
          socket.emit(eventName, data, function () {
              var args = arguments;
              $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                  if (callback) {
                      callback.apply(socket, args);
                  }
              });
          });
      },
      getSocket: function() {
        return socket;
      }

  };
}]);
```

and in my controller.js i do

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function (event) {
  socketio.getSocket().removeAllListeners();
});
```

Comment: @Love-Kesh glad it helps ! rmb to upvote the question or answer!

Comment: @JohnLim You are awesome Man!! working on this issue from last two days. tried many things. Finally this works.

Comment: @srbhbarot glad it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

For broadcast use `socket.broadcast.emit()`

I don't find any socket disconnection listen event code in your client side code.. try adding `socketio.disconnect` for disconnection for client side

And also add a listener to the socket disconnection emit event from server to client ..on the client side by adding `socketio.on('disconnect', function(){do something})`

Comment: Hi Ali, i don't see by adding a disconnect to client side will help me solve the problem but i appreciate you pointed it out.

Comment: Hey @JohnLim could you please elaborate your issue..what keeps up returning multiple time?